Woocommerce shop-2 page is getting empty
I run online shop with Woocommerce and Woodmart template. I run shop on two languages Georgian and english. Shop page on english version: domain.com/en/shop-2 is getting empty in every 1-2 days. I delete shop pages create them again, saving permlink page again also saving settings in Polylang setting and it works but same issue in few days.
I remove pages (shop, shop-2) and create them again, create product-archive layout and saving permlinks page and it works for 1 or 2 day. Then have same problem.
